# I am having a bug with the enemies and when they reach your character in a small game I made

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

The bug happens when you shoot and die at the same time, and in the console it pops up as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'draw' of undefined. Line 65"

The thing is, the bug started happening when I included the function that kills the player, which starts on line 143, and the thing that breaks it is the single line
    enemy = [];

Here's the enemy function

```
function Enemy(x, y) {    
    this.x = x;    
    this.y = y;     

    this.draw = function() {        
        noStroke();        
        fill(255, 0, 0);        
        rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);    
    }     

    this.move = function() {        
        this.x -= movement;    } 
        this.offscreen = function() {        
        if(this.x < 0) {            
            return true;        
        } else {            
            return false;        
        }    
    }

    this.contact = function() {
        for(let i = 0; i < enemy.length; i++) {
            var d = dist(playerx, playery, enemy[i].x, enemy[i].y);
            if(d <= 20) {
                this.kill();
            } 
        }
    }

    this.kill = function() {
      var prevScore = score;

      playerx = width / 10;
      playery = height / 2;

      alert("You died! your score was: " + prevScore);

      fire = [];
      enemy = [];
      score = 0  
    }
}
```

Here's where it says it's getting the type error (which worked perfectly before)
This is lines 55 - 74

```
 for(let i = fire.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {     
    fire[i].draw(); 
    fire[i].move();     
    fire[i].check();     
    if(fire[i].offscreen()) {         
        fire.splice(i, 1);     
    } 
} 

for(let i = enemy.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {     
    enemy[i].draw();     
    enemy[i].move();     
    if(enemy[i].offscreen()) {         
        enemy.splice(i, 1);     
    } 

    if(enemy[i].contact()) {
       enemy[i].kill();
    }        
}
```

The entire code is here: https://code.sololearn.com/Wtza5vElEZ9d/?ref=app
(It's less than 200 lines so not really big)

As well as that bug, I am wanting to find out how it would be possible to make the game gradually get faster. I tried having the frameCount be divided/modulos by a variable (that I had called spawnRate) but when I altered the variable in any way, it just stopped spawning the squares all together.

It's also made with p5.js.

Comment: noone is gonna go through your thousands lines of code... post the relevant part of your code instead

Comment: Hi. You will get more help more quickly if you include the relevant part of the code in the body of your question. Expecting users to wade through the HTML and on into the JS is unlikely to happen. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: If you had looked at the code you'd see that it's actually less than 200 lines and separated from the HTML. I'm gonna change the info in the question though to make it easier. Thank you for letting me know

Comment: You should include your code so that the question still makes sense for future readers when your link breaks. Do you get an error in the console when the bug happens? How exactly do you reproduce the bug? Can you do it consistently?

Answer (score 1):

Your enemy.contact() function is used in if statement so you should return a boolean with that function.

```
this.contact = function() {
    return dist(playerx, playery, this.x, this.y) <= 20;
}
```

It would be better if you make function death() in player object.
It will not be so confusing.